# What is a snapshot in Dart or compilation (not Flutter)?

Tags: dart, compilation

I'm reading about [`dart compile`](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile), and it has a few option: **Executable**, **AOT snapshot**, **JIT snapshot** and **Kernel snapshot** and **JavaScript**.

What is the difference between an executable and a snapshot? Is it purely the fact executables contain the Dart runtime/ VM, whereas a snapshot doesn't. Why is it called a snapshot?

[image]

---

2 highly related question (which I found after posting this question) are:

- [What is the difference between Dart's snapshots and Java bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547163/what-is-the-difference-between-darts-snapshots-and-java-bytecode)
- [What is the snapshot concept in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871476/what-is-the-snapshot-concept-in-dart/12877348#12877348)

This question is different to [Dart: Snapshots vs AOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153618/dart-snapshots-vs-aot), since is asking the difference between a Snapshot and AOT, but actually AOT files are snapshots. It also primarily asked about the differences between Snapshot options (AOT, Kernel, JIT).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An executable (created by `dart compile exe`) is a combination of an AOT snapshot, and the Dart runtime. The Dart runtime is needed to run any Dart code, as it performs critical tasks like managing memory (including garbage collection) and performing runtime type checks.

The three kinds of snapshots (AOT, kernel, and JIT) all contain just the compiled source code. They all need a runtime to be run (typically you just use `dart run <snapshot>`).

The snapshots should perhaps have been named differently. Would 'module' have been easier to understand?

Comment: Thanks! Would it be correct to use "bytecode/bytecode file" instead of 'module' or 'snapshot'? Or is not correct. It seems like this file is similar to Java's `.class` files, which contain Java bytecode. Or, we could just add the definition in the docs: "Snapshot files contain Dart bytecode". I have just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/14595253/7365866 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12877348/7365866 which is also a good read.

Comment: No, that would be incorrect. For example, the AOT snapshot doesn't contain bytecode (i.e. a higher-level set of VM instructions); it contains actual machine code. The kernel snapshots also are not bytecode, but rather a higher level AST representation.

Let me try to see if we can get our docs on this expanded a bit, I can see how this isn't crystal clear.

Answer (score 2):

When Dart code is compiled, it is compiled into intermediary byte code rather than native code. This means that in order for the code to be executed in any arbitrary environment, the compiler needs to include the Dart virtual machine inside the executable along with the user code as well as any portions of the core library the program requires. Usually, this is fine because the Dart runtime is actually quite compact, but the obvious downside to this is that the executable will be larger and start-up time will be longer as the runtime needs to be extracted and warmed up before the user code can be run.

If, however, you are compiling code for an environment where you can guarantee that a Dart runtime will be present (such as a server machine or an IoT device), you can omit the runtime from the compiled program by building a snapshot file rather than an executable. This results in a smaller compiled file with a faster start-up time, although it requires a command to execute and as such is less convenient. You can learn more about snapshots and how to build and execute them [on the Dart GitHib wiki page on snapshots](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Snapshots).

There are three different kinds of snapshots: *Kernel snapshots*, which contain only AST information rather than compiled byte code making them usable by Dart runtimes on any supported architecture (portable but slow); *JIT snapshots*, which contain just the parts of the program necessary for startup and leaves the rest to be interpreted at runtime (fastest startup but slower execution); and *AOT snapshots*, which fully compiles the entire program into byte code (slower startup but fastest execution).

As for why it's called a "snapshot", I couldn't say. If I had to guess, that's because it's a "snapshot" of the program in its compiled state but without the instructions necessary to run it as a standalone executable.

(The above is based on my quick research on the subject and may be missing some key details. If a member of the Dart team happens upon this question, they will probably be able to offer a more detailed and technical explanation.)